# How should I manage dependencies in an Xcode workspace?

Tags: ios, workspace

I'm working on an iOS app project. I have three projects(ProjA, ProjB, ProjC) in my workspace.

- ProjA is my main project, target is an APP
- ProjB and ProjC are Library projects, targets are libProjB.a, libProjC.a
- ProjA should linked to libProjB.a and libProjC.a
- ProjB should linked to libProjC.a

How to set correct dependencies in workspace ? (I have "duplicate symbols" just now)

Comment: if you remove "`libProjC.a`" but continue to include ProjC's headers, do you get rid of the "duplicate symbols" errors?

Comment: Stop linking ProjA to libProjC

Comment: Thanks. I removed ProjB linked to libProjC.a, then set ProjB "User Header Seach Pathes", it works.